# Ansible - include statement

Tags: ansible

I have something like this:

```
  ...
  - name: Include TEST ENV tasks
    include: test_env.yml
    when: test_env
    tags:
      - test
  ...
```

as part of a role.

The thing is it does not behave as I would expect. That is the include takes place only when test_env == True.

The problem is, that include is always executed, but the included tasks are skipped - which does not make sense (for what other reason would i need it?) and the output gets lengthy.

Did I do something wrong or I misuse include statement?

Comment: For me the syntax looks correct. Does running the play in debug return useful information? `ansible-playbook -vvv site.yml `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is how it is supposed to work. The `include` is a special statement and not a module, which gets executed regardless. The `when` will be added to each task. Strange I know.

See the [include statement](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html).

> (‘when‘ provides some ability for hosts to conditionally skip tasks).